# Cannot read character from the list to use in ord()

Tags: python

Write a program that prompts the user for the name of a file, opens the file for reading,
and then outputs how many times each character of the alphabet appears in the file.

```
#!/usr/local/bin/python

name=raw_input("Enter file name: ")
input_file=open(name,"r")
list=input_file.readlines()
count = 0
counter = 0


for i in range(65,91): #from A to Z
    for j in range(0,len(list)):
        if(i == ord(j)):   #problem: ord() takes j as an int here, I want it to get the char at j
            count = count + 1

    print i, count
    count = 0

for k in range(97,123): #from a to z
    for l in range(0,len(list)):
        if(k == ord(l)):  #problem: ord() takes l as an int here, I want it to get the char at l
            counter = counter + 1

    print k, counter
    count = 0
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you simply want to count the frequency of a letter, you can do:

```
in_text = input_file.read()
frequencies = []

for i in range(65,91): #from A to Z
    frequencies.append(in_text.count(chr(i)))

print frequencies
```

Comment: Yeah I tried doing that but for some reason I get this error:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "prob9.py", line 10, in <module>
    if(i == ord(list[j])):
TypeError: ord() expected a character, but string of length 11 found

Comment: Instead of doing `''.join(in_text)` use `input_file.read()` in the first place.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this code to count the time of character.

```
#!/usr/local/bin/python

from collections import defaultdict

name=raw_input("Enter file name: ")
input_file=open(name,"r")
lines=input_file.readlines()

res = defaultdict(int)
for line in lines:
    for c in line:
        res[c] += 1

for k, v in res.items():
    print("%c %d" % (k , v))
```

Answer (score 0):

Just another answer based on `collections.Counter` for a difference.

```
from collections import Counter

filename = raw_input("Enter file name: ")
contents = open(filename, 'r').read()

frequencies = Counter()

for char in contents:
    if char.isalpha():
        frequencies[char] += 1

print frequencies.items()
```

Answer (score 0):

The answer with a lot of these types of things is that someone has already thought of the answer and put in the standard library.

```
from collections import Counter

name=raw_input("Enter file name: ")
input_file=open(name,"r")
data = input_file.read()

c = Counter(data)
```

This gets you the count of all the characters, not just the letters. To get the characters

```
print(sorted(c))
```

To get the 3 most common

```
print(c.most_common(3))
```

If you want only the characters you'll need to filter out the others. One way is using a generator expression.

```
import string
gen = (ch for ch in data if ch in string.ascii_lowercase)
c1 = Counter(gen)
```